# how to delete any content after jquery prepend() inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i am doing a search button and each time the user searches for a movie, i prepend the photos api in the html div. All i want to do is when  a user searches again for another movie i want the previous content to be deleted, ( any content after the prepended one). Here is how my code looks like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Search-Results"></div>
```

**jQUERY:**

```
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {

    for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++)
        {   
        var s = '<span><img src="http://example.com/test.jpg"> </span>';
        $("#Search-Results").prepend(s);
    }
});
```

Example:

When the user searches for avatar movie and then for godfather, i want the avatar images to be deleted. The godfather will be pretended into the div and the avatar photos that are next to godfather will be removed.

**Note** that the code is inside a for loop and i get only 1 image with .html

Comment: Try this:
$('#Search-Results').html(s);

Comment: Does the element `#Search-Results` have other content that must be retained between searches?

Comment: @PeterKA no, it is an empty div

Comment: That should be straight forward. You can use either a combination of `.empty()` and `.prepend()` or `.html()` and `.prepend()` methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
$("#Search-Results").html("");

for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {

      var s = '<span><img src="http://example.com/test.jpg"> </span>'; 
      if (i == 0){
           $("#Search-Results").html(s); 
      }else {
           $("#Search-Results").prepend(s);
      }
}
```

Comment: So, I think you need to display the last photo only?

Comment: No, i search for a movie and i print the photos (array) into the div. I want all photos to appear, not only 1. Each time i search again for another movie i will use those new photos and delete the previous ones.

Comment: Is the results array conatins the searched movie photos ?

Comment: of course it is an api, they contain the urls of the movies.

Comment: it works, it is the same if but with a different way

Answer (score 1):

For the very first photo in the loop use `.html()`, use `.prepend()` for the rest.

```
for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
    var s = '<span><img src="http://example.com/test.jpg"> </span>'; 
    $("#Search-Results")[ i ? 'prepend' : 'html' ]( s ); 
}
```

Comment: Glad I could be of help :-) Enjoy!!

Comment: i have run into some problems, i have uploaded the website at this link: https://wherehd.herokuapp.com/ When i search for gladiator then spiderman both images are appeared.

Comment: While it's not clear what the new problem you're having is, it may be helpful to create a new question that just addresses that problem. Feel free to create a minimal demo that clearly shows what the problem is. As a rule we do not encourage redirects to external sites as there's no guarantee of broken links in the future.

Comment: here is my other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054708/images-arent-cleared-when-using-append-and-html-jquery-methods

Answer (score 0):

This function will simply overwrite the innerHTML

```
$("#Search-Results").html(s);
```

Comment: i have edited my question that my code is inside a for loop and .html may not work. I get only 1 image