# Images aren't cleared when using append and html jquery methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

The user will search for a movie. If the  user will search again for another movie i want the previous content to be deleted, ( any content after the appended one). Here is how my code looks like:

**HTML:**

```
<div id="Search-Results"></div>
```

**jQUERY:**

```
function search() {
    function reset() {

    }

    var movieTitle = $('#search_field').val();
    var str1 = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?include_adult=false&page=1&query=";
    var str2 = "&language=en-US&api_key=xxx";
    var searchResult = str1 + movieTitle + str2;


    //var searchResult = str1.concat(encodeURI(movieTitle)).concat(str2);

    var settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": searchResult,
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {},
        "data": "{}"
    }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function(response) {
        console.log(response);


        var results = response.results;
        var l = results.length;
        var changeline = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < l; i++) {
            var movie = results[i];
            var description = movie.overview;
            var title = movie.title;
            var image = 'https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + movie.poster_path;
            var releaseDate = movie.release_date;

            //Display the description and image
            if (movie.poster_path !== null) {




                var s = '<span id="shell main box"><div class="movie-image" id="shell main"><a href="#"><span class="play"><span class="name"></span></span><img src="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/' + movie.poster_path + '"/></a></div>'; // HTML string
                /*changeline ++;
                     if (changeline == 8)
                     {
                          $("#Search-Results").prepend('<br>');   
                     }    
                     */
                $("#search_field").val(""); //clear value of the input


                if (i === 0) {

                    $("#Search-Results").html(s);
                } else {


                    $("#Search-Results").append(s);

                }
                /*if(typeof results !== "undefined" && results.length > 0){
                $("#Search-Results").html("");
                }

                for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
                $("#Search-Results").append(s);
                }*/
            }

        }
    });


}
```

**Example:**

When the user searches for avatar movie and then for godfather, i want the new results to be appeared and the old ones removed. The godfather photos will be appended into the div and the avatar photos that are next to godfather will be removed. This will happen every time the user will search for another movie.

**The problem:**

This technique seemed to work fine, but with some movie searches the photos aren't deleted. For example, search for the movie "The equalizer" then for "spiderman" And you will see that the equalizer photos aren't deleted.

Example  website: 
https://wherehd.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Would you please post here a complete demo or at least how and when the above loop is triggered. You have not provided enough information for anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: i have updated my complete function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your logic and the following line is key:

```
if (movie.poster_path !== null) {
```

If it turns out that `movie.poster_path == null` when `i = 0` nothing within the `if` clause is executed. Therefore, `.html( s )` is never executed, which is the only way previous content is removed. You can verify that by confirming that for `spiderman` search `movie.poster_path` is `undefined` for the first search result.

There're several approaches you can use to resolve this:
1. Initialize a new counter outside the loop, say `j=0`, increment this counter `j++` at the end of this problematic `if` and replace `i` with `j` in the inner `if`, Or
2. Outside this `if` use the `.empty()` method when `i = 0` and reduce the inner `if` to just a `.prepend(s)`

....you get the drift :-)

Comment: yes you are correct, if i remove that if it works, but i added that if because themoviedb.org api doesn't give me image urls for all the movies.

Comment: thanks a lot, you are genious. By doing your step 1 it solved the problem. 2 also works!!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code instead. This should ensure that the HTML of the search results gets reset every time results are returned.

```
if(typeof results !== "undefined" && results.length > 0){
    $("#Search-Results").html("");
}

for(var i=0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var s = '<span><img src="http://example.com/test.jpg"> </span>'; 
      $("#Search-Results").append(s);
}
```

Comment: i get the same image for all the results

Comment: Did you change the above code to use a different image source?